# C Linux USB Driver | Best way to print URB buffer contents

Tags: c, linux, usb, driver

I'm new to Linux USB driver development, and I absolutely love it so far! I'm currently creating a driver for an Xbox One controller, and I have a question for you guys. In the below code, you will see that I fill an interrupt IN URB in the open function, and I would like to print the contents of the URB buffer in the xb1_int_in_callback() function. What would be the best way to do this? At the moment, I'm using printk(KERN_INFO "int_in_buffer: %s", dev->int_in_buffer), however I don't see the entire URB buffer contents printed, and get a weird string printed to dmesg.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm new to programming and C, so I'm still learning as I go, but I absolutely love it so far!

Code:

```
static void xb1_int_in_callback(struct urb *int_in_urb) {
    struct xb1_controller *dev = int_in_urb->context;

    printk(KERN_INFO "xb1_int_in_callback successfully called");
    printk(KERN_INFO "int_in_buffer: %s", dev->int_in_buffer);
}

static int xb1_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "open function called..");

    struct xb1_controller *dev;
    struct usb_interface *interface;
    int subminor;
    int retval = 0;

    subminor = iminor(inode);

    interface = usb_find_interface(&xb1_driver, subminor);
    if(!interface) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to locate interface in open   
        function");
        retval = -ENODEV;
        goto exit;
    }

    dev = usb_get_intfdata(interface);
        if(!dev) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to locate dev structure in open   
            function");
            retval = -ENODEV;
            goto exit;
        }

    usb_fill_int_urb(dev->int_in_urb, dev->udev, usb_rcvintpipe(dev- 
                 >udev, dev->int_in_endpoint->bEndpointAddress),
                 dev->int_in_buffer, dev->int_in_endpoint- 
                 >wMaxPacketSize, xb1_int_in_callback,
                 dev, dev->int_in_endpoint->bInterval);

    dev->int_in_running = 1;

    retval = usb_submit_urb(dev->int_in_urb, GFP_KERNEL);
    if(retval) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to submit int_in_urb in open 
        function");
        dev->int_in_running = 0;
        goto exit;
    }

    file->private_data = dev;

exit:
    return retval;
}


static int xb1_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct     
usb_device_id *id) {
    struct usb_device *udev = interface_to_usbdev(interface);
    struct xb1_controller *dev = NULL;
    struct usb_host_interface *iface_desc;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint;
    int i;
    int retval = -ENODEV;

    if(!udev) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "udev is NULL in probe function");
        xb1_abort(dev);
        return retval;
    }

    dev = kzalloc(sizeof(struct xb1_controller), GFP_KERNEL);
    if(!dev) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to allocate memory for dev in probe   
        function");
        xb1_abort(dev);
        return retval;
    }

    dev->udev = udev;
    dev->interface = interface;

    iface_desc = interface->cur_altsetting;

    for(i=0; i<iface_desc->desc.bNumEndpoints; i++) {
        endpoint = &iface_desc->endpoint[i].desc;

        if(((endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_DIR_MASK) ==   
        USB_DIR_IN)
           && ((endpoint->bmAttributes & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK) == 
              USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT)) {

            dev->int_in_endpoint = endpoint;
        }
    }

    if(!dev->int_in_endpoint) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to locate interrupt in endpoint for 
        interface in probe function");
        xb1_abort(dev);
        return retval;
    }
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Interrupt in endpoint found!");
    }
```

Comment: Also, I would like to note that dev->int_in_buffer is defined as a char array (char* int_in_buffer)

Comment: Are you're sure that your buffer is a C string? It must have /0 in the end or you may get segmentation fault. Before printing copy it to the string ending with /0. Btw zero bytes in buffer is also problem.

Comment: Yes, it should be I'm assuming. This is what I get when I view dmesg:  ~\xffffffed\xffffff8c\xffffffdd\xffffffe8\xffffffe1 but this doesn't match what I see with my USB sniffing tool

Comment: I cant tell you why you see what you see, your question was the best way to output buffer data. So, you're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing a small buffers (up to 64 bytes long) use printk format:

Raw buffer as a hex string:

```
%*ph    00 01 02  ...  3f
%*phC   00:01:02: ... :3f
%*phD   00-01-02- ... -3f
%*phN   000102 ... 3f
```

For larger buffers use `print_hex_dump()`. Reference [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/hexdump.c#L242).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'll play around with what you advised, and see if I can get things working properly now!